# X11 Forwarding and ROS Visualization Tools

Tags: simulation, turtlebot, turtlebot-simulator

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I have a setup where I would prefer to be able to run my ROS setup remotely. When using X11 forwarding, on Rviz or the Turtlebot Gazebo simulator I get the following.

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'Ogre::RenderingAPIException'
  what():  OGRE EXCEPTION(3:RenderingAPIException): Couldn`t open X display localhost:10.0 in GLXGLSupport::getGLDisplay at /tmp/buildd/ros-electric-visualization-common-1.6.2/debian/ros-electric-visualization-common/opt/ros/electric/stacks/visualization_common/ogre/build/ogre_src_v1-7-3/RenderSystems/GL/src/GLX/OgreGLXGLSupport.cpp (line 788)
[gazebo-1] process has died [pid 5289, exit code -6].
```

Can anyone explain what this error means, and suggest where I could start looking to fix it?

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/27695/x11-forwarding-and-ros-visualization-tools/) by [osuairt](https://answers.ros.org/users/1049/osuairt/) on ROS Answers with karma: 69 on 2012-02-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Ogre and OpenGL in general doesn't play well with X forwarding. ROS is inherently network-aware, so you should instead set ROS_MASTER_URI appropriately on your workstation and run rviz locally.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2012-02-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [osuairt](https://answers.ros.org/users/1049/osuairt/) on 2012-02-21**:
That is really too bad. I am looking for a solution where rendering is done remotely.

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2012-02-21**:
wviz: http://ros.org/wiki/wviz might provide the solution you're looking for.